# How to get Django admin's "Save as new" to work with read-only fields?

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to implement the "Save as new" feature in Django's admin for a model such as this one:

```
class Plasmid (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length = 255, blank=False)
    other_name = models.CharField("Other Name", max_length = 255, blank=True)
    selection = models.CharField("Selection", max_length = 50, blank=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

In the admin, if the user who requests a Plasmid object is NOT the same as the one who created it, some of the above-shown fields are set as read-only. If the user is the same, they are all editable. For example:

```
class PlasmidPage(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):

        if obj:
            if not request.user == obj.created_by:
                return ['name', 'created_by',]
            else:
                return ['created_by',]
        else:
            return []

    def change_view(self,request,object_id,extra_context=None):

        self.fields = ('name', 'other_name', 'selection', 'created_by',)
        return super(PlasmidPage,self).change_view(request,object_id)
```

The issue I have is that when a field is read-only and a user hits the "Save as new" button, the value of that field is not 'transferred' to the new object. On the other hand, the values of fields that are not read-only are transferred.

Does anybody why, or how I could solve this problem? I want to transfer the values of both read-only and non-read-only fields to the new object.

Comment: It might be helpful to share the code used for the admin pages.

Comment: I've edited my original question above, the full code can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/hulrichlab/organisation-intranet/blob/master/collection_management/admin.py#L806)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try  [Field.disabled](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#disabled) attribute?

> The disabled boolean argument, when set to True, disables a form field using the disabled HTML attribute so that it won’t be editable by users. Even if a user tampers with the field’s value submitted to the server, it will be ignored in favor of the value from the form’s initial data.

I did a quick test in my project. When I added a new entry the disabled fields were sent to the server.
So something like this should work for you:

```py
class PlasmidPage(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_form(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = super(PlasmidPage, self).get_form(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if not request.user == self.cleaned_data['created_by'].:
            form.base_fields['created_by'].disabled = True
            form.base_fields['name'].disabled = True

    def change_view(self,request,object_id,extra_context=None):

        self.fields = ('name', 'other_name', 'selection', 'created_by',)
        return super(PlasmidPage,self).change_view(request,object_id)
```

Comment: I tried and I doesn't work for me, it behaves the same way as setting those fields to read-only

Comment: What happens if you activate the field in the UI changing the HTML in the browser? Is the field sent to the server?

It's just an idea but maybe you can create a custom admin page in order to send the info you want to the server.

Comment: That doesn't work either. I think I'll open a ticket with the Django team to see what they say

Answer (score 0):

It happens because Django uses request.POST data to build a new object, but readonly fields are not sent with the request body. You can overcome this by making widget readonly, not the field itself, like this:

`form.fields['name'].widget.attrs = {'readonly': True}`

This has a drawback: it's still possible to change field values by tampering the form (e.g if you remove this readonly attribute from the widget using devtools console). You could protect from that by checking that values haven't actually changed in `clean()` method.

So full solution will be:

```
class PlasmidForm(models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Plasmid

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance and not self.instance.created_by == request.user:
            self.fields['name'].widget.attrs = {'readonly': True}

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        if self.instance and not self.instance.created_by == request.user:
            self.cleaned_data['name'] = instance.name  # just in case user tampered with the form
        return cleaned_data


class PlasmidAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PlasmidForm
    readonly_fields = ('created_by',)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if obj.created_by is None:
            obj.created_by = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Notice I left `created_by` to be readonly, and instead populate it with the current user whenever object is saved. I don't think you really want to transfer this property from another object.